# Making Thumbnails of same Size in view of MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I do have a View where there is multiple tiles or Thumnails in row  that  are arranged in Disorder i want that the all the tiles must be of same Size and i am defining the Title and Description in that thumbnails so because description is Multiline text i want to short it and Display it in that thumbnail so is there any Function like Substring()?i am doing this with the model

```
public string ContentMetaDataTitle{get;set;}
        public string ShortDescription
        {
            get
            {
                var text = ContentMetaDataTitle;
                if (text.Length > 21)
                {
                    text = text.Remove(19);
                    text += "..";
                }
                return text;
            }
        }
```

and added the CSS for tiles as follows:

```
.pin {
-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
column-break-inside: avoid;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 2px 5px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #eee;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

this is how i have define my view:

```
<div class="pin video selectable" data-val="800034" data-type="Video" data-title="BTSScratchcard Ad.mov">

<span class="picBox">
        <a class="fancy" rel="_pic" title="BTSScratchcard Ad.mov" href="/Watch?height=350&amp;width=600&amp;file=http%3A%2F%2Fvidzapper.vidzapper.com%2Fdev%2Fbtsscratchcard-ad_mov_20130522021206.xml&amp;autoplay=True&amp;poster=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.vidzapper.com%2Fvidzapper.vidzapper.com%2Fdev%2Fbtsscratchcard-ad_mov_20130522021206-2.png%3Fw%3D650%26h%3D365&amp;v=3&amp;skin=tubecss">
            <img src="http://images.vidzapper.com/vidzapper.vidzapper.com/dev/btsscratchcard-ad_mov_20130522021206-2.png?w=280&amp;h=0" title="BTSScratchcard Ad.mov" alt="BTSScratchcard Ad.mov">
        </a>
</span>    <div class="title">BTSScratchcard Ad.mov</div>
    <div class="description">BTSScratchcard Ad.mov</div>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-small" href="/Meta/Edit/800034" title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-small" href="/Meta/Details/800034" title="Details"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-small" href="/Meta/Details/800034?delete=True" title="Delete"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-small btnReEncode" href="/Meta/Encode/800034" title="Re-Encode"><i class="icon-repeat"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-small fancy" href="/Watch?height=350&amp;width=600&amp;file=http%3A%2F%2Fvidzapper.vidzapper.com%2Fdev%2Fbtsscratchcard-ad_mov_20130522021206.xml&amp;autoplay=True&amp;poster=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.vidzapper.com%2Fvidzapper.vidzapper.com%2Fdev%2Fbtsscratchcard-ad_mov_20130522021206-2.png%3Fw%3D650%26h%3D365&amp;v=3&amp;skin=tubecss" title="Play"><i class="icon-play"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-small" href="/Meta/Share/800034" title="Share"><i class="icon-share-alt"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-small xmlDownload dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon-download"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-small light" href="/Comment/Meta/800034" title="Comments"><i class="icon-comment"></i></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

please suggest me!!!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is this code doing, and what did you expect/want it to do?

Comment: i want to say that i do have multiples thumbnails in which i am showing an image but that are not arranged in order,means one is lower and other is upper i want that they must be arranged in one line...

Comment: and how i can short the string value that i am fetching from the model to show only some text of it in my view

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? I don't see any references to any image in the code you posted.

Comment: i have edited the code for view

Comment: It will be a lot easier to suggest CSS solutions (which i expect is what you need) if you can show us the generated HTML (view source in browser).

Answer (score 0):

Let CSS do the work for you. Add a width and then add:

```
white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;
```